# Does LPG (cooking gas) react with water?

Tags: food-chemistry

If cooking gas (or LPG) was exposed to some water in the gasline system, what would be the resultant by-product, and would this induce flame into the cylinder for explosion?

[image]

Comment: LPG is a mixture of hydrocarbon gases (propane and butane) and the mixture will have non-polar character. Water is polar. Many chemistry students learn that non-polar can not react well with polar substances (and vice versa), thus you will not observe like chemical explosion like you wrote. If they are not react, you might want to check the fact about their solubility. From there, we know that the mixtures are slightly soluble in water, it means that there is tendency that the water will evaporate (and the evaporation does depend on the temperature of the system).

Comment: @làntèrn While your comment might be useful for OP, it is inaccurate. Even quite low solubility may be enough; not to say that substances can react on interfaces between the phases. Also in specific conditions H2O and  hydrocarbons may react - in vapor phase, at very high temperature, when O2 isn't present.

Comment: Everything that comes out of a refinery has been exposed to water and contains residual water in the ppm range or lower. A menial job in a refinery is to occasionally open valves on the storage tanks to drain water ( that has separated from the product) into the refinery sewer system. And corrosion inhibitor is added to products going into pipelines to prevent corrosion of the steel pipe by water continuing to separate from the hydrocarbons

Comment: @Mithoron Well, the OP doesn't tell about the temperature and I know the temperature does impact on interfacial phenomena of the mixtures. I do learn it but given the OP information, it is not suffice enough to explain the outcome of the system. Perhaps it is not too good to elevate one thing to some extents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It produces water after combustion, so it does not react with it.